# How to improve load time of Kendo grid in a aspx page?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

We are using kendo grid control in our aspx page. We have significant amount of data in the grid. currently the load time of the page is around 5-7 seconds. Is there any smart tricks to reduce the load time? We are trying reduce the load time to 3-4 seconds. We are populating the grid using REST service. We have already removed the duplicate REST calls & unnecessary parameters form the REST web service.
We would really appreciate a prompt response on this.

Thanks in advance

Lalatendu

Answer (score 1):

Do you have time on where are you spending time?

1. Things that you can try: do not load full kendo.all.min.js but only what you need. There is a very good blog on this in Kendo UI website [Using UI Libraries Without the Bloat](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/using-ui-libraries-without-the-bloat/)
2. Use [`serverPaging`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverPaging) in order to transfer less data.
3. You might also consider using [virtual scrolling](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-scrollable.virtual)